# Why in flex with column direction, aspect-ratio is not respected?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 images put into a flexbox with column direction. I want those 3 images each being displayed within their own square containers (1:1 aspect ratio). However, it's not working because of the height. (So three images, each displayed as a square)

If I change flex direction to row, things are working correctly. If I use grid layout for Images with grid-template-row: repeat(3, 1fr), it's also working correctly.

Why flex with column direction doesn't work? Thanks!

```css
.Container {
  width: 258px;
}

.Images {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ImageContainer {
  flex: 1 1 calc(100%/3);
  aspect-ratio: 1/ 1;
}

.Image {
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Images">
    <div class="ImageContainer">
      <img class="Image" src="https://www.simplilearn.com/ice9/free_resources_article_thumb/css-advance-3.JPG">
    </div>
    
    <div class="ImageContainer">
      <img class="Image" src="https://www.simplilearn.com/ice9/free_resources_article_thumb/css-advance-3.JPG">
    </div>
    
    <div class="ImageContainer">
      <img class="Image" src="https://www.simplilearn.com/ice9/free_resources_article_thumb/css-advance-3.JPG">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the `aspect-ratio` to the image instead

```css
.Container {
  width: 258px;
}

.Images {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ImageContainer {
  flex: 1 1 calc(100%/3);
  border:1px solid;
}

.Image {
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Images">
    <div class="ImageContainer">
      <img class="Image" src="https://www.simplilearn.com/ice9/free_resources_article_thumb/css-advance-3.JPG">
    </div>
    <div class="ImageContainer">
      <img class="Image" src="https://www.simplilearn.com/ice9/free_resources_article_thumb/css-advance-3.JPG">
    </div>
    <div class="ImageContainer">
      <img class="Image" src="https://www.simplilearn.com/ice9/free_resources_article_thumb/css-advance-3.JPG">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool. Would you explain the difference between applying aspect-ratio to img vs to div?

Comment: @HanXIAO since the only content inside the div is the image, it's easier to define the ratio on the image and the div will follow automatically.